# ASCII: Cannot invoke length() on the primitive type int

Tags: java

As a part of creating a hash table, I need to convert symbols of a  String to ASCII and I need the length of that ASCII. I found on this site that it's enought to cast int in front of a string to convert it to ASCII but I can't use it as an object.

```
public int hash(String x) {


    int stringLength = x.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {

        char character = x.charAt(i);
        int ascii = (int) character;
        int z = ascii.length();
}
```

I expect to get some integer methods but it doesn't seem to work and I get the error `Cannot invoke length() on the primitive type int` at `ascii.length()`;

Comment: Prinitive types don’t have methods.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the ascii.length()?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so casting int doesn't work for me right? Do you know any other method to convert from a symbol to ascii?

Comment: `final byte[] theBytes = x.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);`?

Comment: I need the length of the ascii of the symbol for the next for loop where I need to have access to the length.

Comment: The length of the ascii for a character (assuming you interpret your String in ascii encoding) is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are trying to get the value of a character as this is effectively the ascii code:

To do this use the Character class rather than the char primitive:

```
public int hash(String x) {


    int stringLength = x.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {

        Character character = x.charAt(i);
        int ascii = character.charValue();

}
```

Comment: This make a lot more sense than what I understood, but then I can't figure out what they tried to do with the `int z`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to have access to the length of ascii, but if I now write int lengthOfAscii = ascii.length() it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Primitives are not objects and cannot be dereferenced.

What you can do is use an Integer, which is a class wrapping an int, use its toString() method and use length() on the result.

Something like

```
char character = x.charAt(i);
int z = Integer.valueOf((int) character).toString().length();
```

(Edited because valueOf doesn't take a char)

This would tell you how many digits the character's code decimal representation has. I can't figure out why you would need it, but it's how I understood your question.

Answer (score -1):

To get the length of the ASCII code, you can convert the value to a string and get the length of that:

```java
public int hash(String x) {

    int stringLength = x.length();
    String value;
    int ascii, asciiLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {

        ascii = x.charAt(i); // chars are just fancy numbers. This does an implicit cast to int
        value = Integer.toString(ascii);
        asciiLength = value.length();
    }

}
```

[Demo](https://tio.run/##ZU/NTsMwDL7vKaxKlVJtVEjcKBwGXJDgxBE4eEnWZXTplLhVB@qzFyeZUAFfbPn7s/fY48VefUyyQe/hGY2Fr8Xi2G0aI8ETEre@NQoODIkXcsbWr@@ArvZFYAJX2sIAt5DhRqr13f0DDKfPrJoCbCyxU6A8aVvTjmlD2cRRFNXcocem02kTROilMavUkjRh29aBCATDVpcVt5tfAbxZLn@uCxUtYq7coVuTMOfgUDGVwUdLutaupDadI6JqRpwdwvQo@/NH/OXkSR/KtqPyyDa0FVkuryG/UiByVbzZbJUe@//e2WWcxnH6Bg)